# Count lines of code in directory using Python

Tags: python, lines-of-code

I have a project whose lines of code I want to count. Is it possible to count all the lines of code in the file directory containing the project by using Python?

Comment: Use [```os.walk```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to traverse the files and sub directories, use [```endswith```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) to filter the files you want to count, ```open``` each file and use ```sum(1 for line in f)``` to count the lines, aggregate all the file line counts.

Comment: The built-in utility wc probably deserves mention here despite not being python.  wc -l filename will return the number of lines in filename much faster than the pure python methods suggested in the answers.

Comment: Here's more on [lines of code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/diseconomies-of-scale-and-lines-of-code/) in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def countLinesInPath(path,directory):
    count=0
    for line in open(join(directory,path), encoding="utf8"):
        count+=1
    return count

def countLines(paths,directory):
    count=0
    for path in paths:
        count=count+countLinesInPath(path,directory)
    return count

def getPaths(directory):
    return [f for f in listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, f))]

def countIn(directory):
    return countLines(getPaths(directory),directory)
```

To count all the lines of code in the files in a directory, call the "countIn" function, passing the directory as a parameter.

Comment: Doesn't python already have a `len(file.readlines())`? And that's just one way I know of

Comment: Yeah I think that could work too, this doesn't take that much more code though

Answer (score 37):

Here's a function I wrote to count all lines of code in a python package and print an informative output. It will count all lines in all .py

```
import os

def countlines(start, lines=0, header=True, begin_start=None):
    if header:
        print('{:>10} |{:>10} | {:<20}'.format('ADDED', 'TOTAL', 'FILE'))
        print('{:->11}|{:->11}|{:->20}'.format('', '', ''))

    for thing in os.listdir(start):
        thing = os.path.join(start, thing)
        if os.path.isfile(thing):
            if thing.endswith('.py'):
                with open(thing, 'r') as f:
                    newlines = f.readlines()
                    newlines = len(newlines)
                    lines += newlines

                    if begin_start is not None:
                        reldir_of_thing = '.' + thing.replace(begin_start, '')
                    else:
                        reldir_of_thing = '.' + thing.replace(start, '')

                    print('{:>10} |{:>10} | {:<20}'.format(
                            newlines, lines, reldir_of_thing))


    for thing in os.listdir(start):
        thing = os.path.join(start, thing)
        if os.path.isdir(thing):
            lines = countlines(thing, lines, header=False, begin_start=start)

    return lines
```

To use it, just pass the directory you'd like to start in. For example, to count the lines of code in some package `foo`:

```
countlines(r'...\foo')
```

Which would output something like:

```
     ADDED |     TOTAL | FILE               
-----------|-----------|--------------------
        5  |        5  | .\__init__.py       
       539 |       578 | .\bar.py          
       558 |      1136 | .\baz\qux.py
```

Comment: `import io` and try using `io.open` instead of `open` if anyone has issues using python2

Comment: Ah ok, wasn't obvious ... first I wanted to know what 'ADDED' was all about? Then I realized that your 'TOTAL' is actually a cumulative count of the 'ADDED'.

Comment: but `5+539!=578`

Comment: You can add `newlines = list(filter(lambda l : l.replace(" ", "")  not in ['\n', '\r\n'], newlines))` between `newlines = f.readlines()` and `newlines = len(newlines)` to not count empty lines.

Comment: You can also add `newlines = list(filter(lambda l : not l.startswith("#"), newlines))` to remove single line comments.

Comment: small bug when `start == '.'`. the '.' gets removed from the extension when printing. can be fixed by doing `reldir_of_thing = '.' + thing.replace(begin_start, '') if begin_start != '.' else thing` instead of the corresponding line. same for the other case.

Answer (score 32):

As an addition to the `pygount` answer, they just added the option `--format=summary` to get the total number of lines in different file types in a directory.

```
pygount --format=summary ./your-directory
```

could output somthing like

```
  Language     Code    %     Comment    %
-------------  ----  ------  -------  ------
XML            1668   48.56       10    0.99
Python          746   21.72      150   14.90
TeX             725   21.11       57    5.66
HTML            191    5.56        0    0.00
markdown         58    1.69        0    0.00
JSON             37    1.08        0    0.00
INI              10    0.29        0    0.00
Text              0    0.00      790   78.45
__duplicate__     0    0.00        0    0.00
-------------  ----  ------  -------  ------
Sum total      3435             1007
```

Answer (score 28):

`pygount` will display all the files in the folder, each with a count of codes lines (excluding documentation)

https://pypi.org/project/pygount/

```
pip install pygount
```

To list the results for the current directory run:

```
pygount ~/path_to_directory
```

Comment: This program manages to fill out my 16 GB of RAM and in turn renders my computer inoperable.

Comment: Managed to make it work by excluding my venv's and only consider .py files with: `pygount --suffix=py --folders-to-skip=venv,venv2 .`

Comment: pygount appears to need to run on LINUX to run as a command line tool as explained on its pypi webpages. It defintely doesn't run as described on Windows.

Answer (score 12):

This has a slight air of homework assignment :-) -- nonetheless, it's a worthwhile exercise, and Bryce93's formatting is nice. I think many would be unlikely to use Python for this given that it can be done quickly with a couple of shell commands, for example:

```
cat $(find . -name "*.py") | grep -E -v '^\s*$|^\s*#' | wc -l
```

Note that none of these solutions accounts for multiline (`'''`) comments.

Comment: Short and good enough for me! In case someone like me does not want to include you can use `cat *.py` in the first step instead.

Comment: This "just worked" for me on Mac OS - thank you!

Comment: This is perfect if you are looking for a ballpark total number. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is derived from Daniel's answer (though refactored enough that this won't be obvious). That one doesn't recurse through subdirectories, which is the behavior I wanted.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, isdir, join

def item_line_count(path):
    if isdir(path):
        return dir_line_count(path)
    elif isfile(path):
        return len(open(path, 'rb').readlines())
    else:
        return 0

def dir_line_count(dir):
    return sum(map(lambda item: item_line_count(join(dir, item)), listdir(dir)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one, using `pathlib`. Lists individual (relative) file paths with line count, total number of files, and total line count.

```py
import pathlib


class LoC(object):
    suffixes = ['.py']
    skip = ['name of dir or file to skip', ...]

    def count(self, path, init=True):
        path = pathlib.Path(path)
        if path.name in self.skip:
            print(f'skipped: {path.relative_to(self.root)}')
            return
        if init:
            self.root = path
            self.files = 0
            self.lines = 0
        if path.is_dir():
            # recursive case
            for item in path.iterdir():
                self.count(path=item, init=False)
        elif path.is_file() and path.suffix in self.suffixes:
            # base case
            with path.open(mode='r') as f:
                line_count = len(f.readlines())
            print(f'{path.relative_to(self.root)}: {line_count}')
            self.files += 1
            self.lines += line_count
        if init:
            print(f'\n{self.lines} lines in {self.files} files')
```

Note I omitted the `__init__` method for clarity.

Usage example:

```py
loc = LoC()
loc.count('/path/to/your/project/directory')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count how many lines are in your project, create a script inside of your project folder and paste the following into it:

```
import os

directory = "[project_directory]"
directory_depth = 100 # How deep you would like to go
extensions_to_consider = [".py", ".css"]  # Change to ["all"] to include all extensions
exclude_filenames = ["venv", ".idea", "__pycache__", "cache"]
skip_file_error_list = True

this_file_dir = os.path.realpath(__file__)

print("Path to ignore:", this_file_dir)
print("=====================================")
def _walk(path, depth):
    """Recursively list files and directories up to a certain depth"""
    depth -= 1
    with os.scandir(path) as p:
        for entry in p:

            skip_entry = False
            for fName in exclude_filenames:
                if entry.path.endswith(fName):
                    skip_entry = True
                    break

            if skip_entry:
                print("Skipping entry", entry.path)
                continue

            yield entry.path
            if entry.is_dir() and depth > 0:
                yield from _walk(entry.path, depth)

print("Caching entries")
files = list(_walk(directory, directory_depth))
print("=====================================")

print("Counting Lines")
file_err_list = []
line_count = 0
len_files = len(files)
for i, file_dir in enumerate(files):

    if file_dir == this_file_dir:
        print("=[Rejected file directory", file_dir, "]=")
        continue

    if not os.path.isfile(file_dir):
        continue

    skip_File = True
    for ending in extensions_to_consider:
        if file_dir.endswith(ending) or ending == "all":
            skip_File = False

    if not skip_File:
        try:
            file = open(file_dir, "r")
            local_count = 0
            for line in file:
                if line != "\n":
                    local_count += 1
            print("({:.1f}%)".format(100*i/len_files), file_dir, "|", local_count)
            line_count += local_count
            file.close()
        except:
            file_err_list.append(file_dir)
            continue
print("=====================================")
print("File Count Errors:", len(file_err_list))
if not skip_file_error_list:
    for file in file_err_list:
        print(file_err_list)

print("=====================================")
print("Total lines |", line_count)
```

There's probably faster and more efficient ways to do this, but this is a nice start.

## Variable Information

`directory` is the project directory you want to be counted

`directory_depth` is how deep within the project infastructure
i.e. a depth of 3 would mean it will only scan the following depth:

- project_dir

  - sub_dir

    - sub2_dir

`extensions_to_consider` is the file extensions to count code. If you only want to count .py files, you set `extensions_to_consider = [".py"]`

`exclude_filenames` is an array of file names (and directories) you don't want to consider the script to count code for.

`skip_file_error_list` is a boolean variable. If you wish to see a printout of all errors while counting, set to True. Otherwise set to False.

## How To Run

Run script using the Python compiler.
To run in terminal

`python path_to_file.py`

or

`python3 path_to_file.py`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

**Use radon**

```
python3 -mpip install radon

radon raw -s pkg_dir/

** Total **
    LOC: 2994
    LLOC: 1768
    SLOC: 1739
    Comments: 71
    Single comments: 29
    Multi: 818
    Blank: 408
    - Comment Stats
        (C % L): 2%
        (C % S): 4%
        (C + M % L): 30%
```

**it will also calculate cyclomatic complexity**

```
a@debian:~/build/clean/scte35-threefive$ radon cc  -a threefive
threefive/base.py
    M 61:4 SCTE35Base.kv_clean - A
    M 85:4 SCTE35Base.load - A
    M 95:4 SCTE35Base._chk_var - A
    C 9:0 SCTE35Base - A
    M 34:4 SCTE35Base.as_hms - A
    M 79:4 SCTE35Base._chk_nbin - A
    M 17:4 SCTE35Base.__repr__ - A
    M 20:4 SCTE35Base.as_90k - A
    M 27:4 SCTE35Base.as_ticks - A
    M 48:4 SCTE35Base.get - A
    M 54:4 SCTE35Base.get_json - A
threefive/bitn.py
    C 9:0 BitBin - A
    M 30:4 BitBin.as_int - A
    M 47:4 BitBin.as_charset - A
    C 99:0 NBin - A
    M 133:4 NBin.add_int - A
    M 170:4 NBin.reserve - A

      ..... 
246 blocks (classes, functions, methods) analyzed.
Average complexity: A (1.9024390243902438)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bryce93's answer, with `code_only` option to exclude comments, docstrings, and empty lines from line count:

```py
import os

def countlines(rootdir, total_lines=0, header=True, begin_start=None,
               code_only=True):
    def _get_new_lines(source):
        total = len(source)
        i = 0
        while i < len(source):
            line = source[i]
            trimline = line.lstrip(" ")

            if trimline.startswith('#') or trimline == '':
                total -= 1
            elif '"""' in trimline:  # docstring begin
                if trimline.count('"""') == 2:  # docstring end on same line
                    total -= 1
                    i += 1
                    continue
                doc_start = i
                i += 1
                while '"""' not in source[i]:  # docstring end
                    i += 1
                doc_end = i
                total -= (doc_end - doc_start + 1)
            i += 1
        return total

    if header:
        print('{:>10} |{:>10} | {:<20}'.format('ADDED', 'TOTAL', 'FILE'))
        print('{:->11}|{:->11}|{:->20}'.format('', '', ''))

    for name in os.listdir(rootdir):
        file = os.path.join(rootdir, name)
        if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith('.py'):
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                source = f.readlines()

            if code_only:
                new_lines = _get_new_lines(source)
            else:
                new_lines = len(source)
            total_lines += new_lines

            if begin_start is not None:
                reldir_of_file = '.' + file.replace(begin_start, '')
            else:
                reldir_of_file = '.' + file.replace(rootdir, '')

            print('{:>10} |{:>10} | {:<20}'.format(
                    new_lines, total_lines, reldir_of_file))

    for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
        file = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            total_lines = countlines(file, total_lines, header=False,
                                     begin_start=rootdir, code_only=code_only)
    return total_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a variant of @Bryce93 's response for a python + flask project(s)... ran some pivot tables on the outcome .csv file and the like (I manually marked files as 'active' downstream)... cheers

```
import os
import pandas as pd


def countlines(start, begin_start=None):
    global files

    for thing in os.listdir(start):
        thing = os.path.join(start, thing)
        if os.path.isfile(thing):
            if thing.endswith('.py') or thing.endswith('.html'):
                with open(thing, 'r') as f:
                    lines = f.readlines()
                    count = len([l for l in lines if not l.strip().startswith('#')])
                    functions, classes, comments = 0, 0, 0
                    if thing.endswith('.py'):
                        functions = len([
                            l for l in lines if l.strip().startswith('def ') 
                            and l.strip().endswith('):')
                        ])
                        classes = len([
                            l for l in lines if l.strip().startswith('class ') 
                            and l.strip().endswith('):')
                        ])
                        comments = len([l for l in lines if l.strip().startswith('#')])
                        language = 'python'
                    elif thing.endswith('.html'):
                        comments = len([l for l in lines if l.strip().startswith('<!--')])
                        language = 'jinja'
                    else:
                        raise Exception(thing)

                    path = str(thing)
                    folder = '/'.join(path.split(repo)[-1].split('/')[:-1])

                    files.append({
                        'path': path,
                        'repo': repo,
                        'language': language,
                        'filetype': thing.split('.')[-1],
                        'folder': folder,
                        'filename': thing.split('/')[-1],
                        'lines': count,
                        'functions': functions,
                        'classes': classes,
                        'comments': comments,
                    })

    for thing in os.listdir(start):
        thing = os.path.join(start, thing)
        if os.path.isdir(thing):
            countlines(thing, begin_start=start)


files = []
repo = '<repo1>'
countlines('<path>/<repo1>')
master = pd.DataFrame(files)
files = []
repo = '<repo2>'
countlines('<path>/<repo2>')
master = pd.concat([master, pd.DataFrame(files)], ignore_index=False, sort=False)
master['active'] = False
master.sort_values(by=['repo', 'folder', 'language', 'filename'])

master.to_csv('../<blah>.csv')
```

Comment: You're missing the triple quoted comments

Comment: true, but there are/could also be some triple-quoted sql queries. So I'm willing to take the loss. good point @LeroyScandal

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple recursive function which prints total LOC of files in each folder and in the end it returns the total LOC of the directory you passed in initially:

```
import os

def find_loc(cd = os.curdir):
    listdir = os.listdir(cd)
    if len(listdir) == 0:
        return 0
    loc = 0;
    files = []
    folders = []
    next_dirs = []
    for x in listdir:
        path = os.path.join(cd, x)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            files.append(x)
            file = open(path, 'r')
            for line in file:
                if line == '':
                    continue
                loc += 1
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            folders.append(x)
            next_dirs.append(path)
    print(f'cd: {cd}')
    print(f'files ({len(files)}): {files}')
    print(f'dirs: {folders}')
    print(f'loc: {loc}\n')
    for next_dir in next_dirs:
        loc += find_loc(next_dir)
    return loc

find_loc()
```

`cd` param in the `find_loc` function is the directory from which you wish to start counting the LOC.

Comment: How does this improve on the existing answers?